# Pyramid config .ini files, setup.py and requirements.txt

Tags: python, pyramid, setup.py

I just started learning **Pyramid** using the official documentation and I found it very cool so far.
Unfortunately, while the basic one-file app is really simple and straight, I'm having an hard time trying to understand how a "serious app", generated using the `pcreate` scaffolding command (`alchemy` in my case), is supposed to be handled.
For example:

- is `setup.py` mandatory or can I just use `requirements.txt` as I'm used to do with **Django** in order to install dependencies?
- if I have to rely on `setup.py` am I supposed to execute `python setup.py develop` each time I create/delete a new file (since I saw them listed in `SOURCES.txt`)?
- In `settings.ini` how "`use`" (under `[app:main]`) works? (can I "bypass" the `egg-info` which is it pointing to and "bootrsapping" the app in an alternative way?)

Answer (score 2):

There are several tutorials that addresses all these topics, and provide references to further relevant reading for each step along the way. I suggest starting with the [Quick Tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/index.html).

To answer your bullet points in order:

- `setup.py` is a standard for installing Python packages and dependencies and testing your app.
- If you need to install more packages as a result of your changes, then yes. **EDIT:** It is now recommended to use `pip install -e .` for installing more packages. Also while developing, you can use `pserve development.ini --reload` which will monitor file changes and restart the server for you.
- For more information about the meaning of the `use = egg:MyProject`, see [Entry Points and PasteDeploy .ini Files](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/paste.html#pastedeploy-entry-points). There are many ways to configure Pyramid apps including [Application Configuration](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/configuration.html) and [Advanced Configuration](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/advconfig.html).

Answer (score 1):

You chose Pyramid, the best Python web microframework, a very choice! Here are some pointers for further insight. Actually your question is not specific to Pyramid, but generally how Python packages and applications generally work.

> is setup.py mandatory or can I just use requirements.txt as I'm used to do with Django in order to install dependencies?

It is not. You can use requirement.txt. setup.py `install_dependencies` is mainly for libraries. [For more information read blog post Declaring dependencies in Python](http://blog.ziade.org/2013/04/13/declaring-dependencies-in-python/).

> if I have to rely on setup.py am I supposed to execute python setup.py develop each time I create/delete a new file (since I saw them listed in SOURCES.txt)?

It's not necessary.

> In settings.ini how "use" (under [app:main]) works? (can I "bypass" the egg-info which is it pointing to and "bootrsapping" the app in an alternative way?)

Please see the other answer regarding Paster and Entry points.